# create associative array from array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I transform

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Some Text
    [1] => Some Other Text (+£14.20)
    [2] => Text Text (+£26.88)
    [3] => Another One (+£68.04)
)
```

Into associative array like the one below:

```
Array2
(
    [Some Text] => 0 //0 since there is no (+£val) part
    [Some Other Text] => 14.20
    [Text Text] => Text Text 26.88
    [Another One] => 68.04
)
```

Comment: What do you have so far, and how does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach( $oldArray as $str ) {
    if( preg_match( '/^(.+)\s\(\+£([\d\.]+)\)$/', $str, $matches ) ) {
        $newArray[ $matches[1] ] = (double)$matches[2];
    } else {
        $newArray[ $str ] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$a2 = array();
foreach ($Array1 as $a1) {
    if (strpos($a1, '(') > 0) {
      $text = substr($a1, 0, strpos($a1, '('));
      $value = substr($a1, strpos($a1, '(')+3, strpos($a1, ')')-1);
    } else {
      $text = $a1;
      $value = 0;
    }
    $a2[$text] = $value;    
}
print_r($a2);
```

EDIT:

You can do this using explode method as well:

```
$a2 = array();
foreach ($Array1 as $a1) {
    $a1explode = explode("(", $a1, 2);
    $text = $a1explode[0];
    if ($a1explode[1]) {
       $value = substr($a1explode[1],3);
    } else {
       $value = 0;
    }
    $a2[$text] = $value;    
}
print_r($a2);
```

Comment: regular expressions and explode are other options depending on the consistency of the data.

Comment: Thanks Its close but its not working in situations where   "some text (text text) (+£14.20)"

Comment: "(" to "(+"  now there is only one round bracket at the end  " [text text ] => 7.18) "